# No space found error on device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I try to Install my application  on android emulator it gives error: no space found on device .How can I increase the internal memory of my emulator so that I can install my application on same emulator without creating new AVD.Size of my application is approx 18 MB,and free internal memory of my emulator 17 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to the following link for better clarification the heap size increasing

http://androidforums.com/application-development/48495-memory-size-emulator.html